# Confusing conditional

Tags: conditionals

I have come across sentences using past tense in if-clause and present tense in the main clause, such as:

1) A hamster is pregnant for only about three weeks and up to 20 babies can seemingly appear overnight in a hamster's nest if you didn't know your hamster was pregnant.

2) Hamsters will eat more when they are pregnant and nursing, but otherwise their diet will remain the same as if they weren't.

Are they grammatically correct and do you classify them as "mixed conditionals"?

Comment: These are grammatical. Native English speakers don't classify conditionals as 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and mixed. They are all conditionals. They come in two kinds, real and unreal, and if the main clause and dependent clause are set at different time periods, they use the tenses appropriate for those time periods. So there are really four different types of mixed conditionals, For both hypothetical and real conditionals, the if-clause can be in past and main clause in the present, or the other way around. Don't try to just memorize all these four combinations—understand the logic behind them.

Comment: '[as] if they weren't' in the second is the irrealis 'were' usage. You can look up "if I were" here and elsewhere. // I find your first sentence jarring, pairing 'can appear' with 'if you didn't know'. I'd rephrase.

Comment: ...also don't get too committed to learning *their diet will remain the same as if they **weren't*** if you find that one confusing. So do many/most native speakers, who happily use ***...as if they aren't*** in such contexts.

Comment: Thanks all of you 

Comment: The conditional (2) is rather strange, as @FumbleFingers remarks; *will remain* is the verb tense of the main clause of a present real conditional, and *weren't* has the verb tense of the *if* clause of a present unreal conditional. It's quite rare to mix unreal and real clauses in the same conditional, but here it sounds reasonably natural to me (although many native speakers would use *aren't* instead, making it a 1st conditional).